# AM437x ZDN (N491 BGA) Footprint Dimensions

Tags: footprint, bga, pad

I have downloaded and studied the layout that TI provides for the TMDSEVM437X AM437x Evaluation Module. After calculating some distances, I concluded that the pad size used for the ZDN footprint is 0.28 mm x 0.28 mm. It is a 0.65 mm pitch BGA. However, the recommended from TI pad size is 0.4 mm x 0.4 mm. Would 0.28 mm be ok?

Comment: I would stick to the recommended pad size, or try to stick close to it. Too small and you might get alignment problems.

Answer (score 1):

I have received an answer on this from TI forum. I am posting it here:

*The AM437x nominal ball size is 0.42mm +/-0.06mm. The IPC recommended pad size reduction for this ball size is 20%, which would give a pad size of 0.336mm. However variation of +/-0.05mm is allowed for this pad size, which makes 0.28mm pad size absolutely acceptable.*